# Replace Drawables in Custom Android Build

Tags: android, drawable, rom

This question is for developers who are creating ROMS/custom builds of the Android OS. I want to create my own ROM, and I'm just wondering where the UI drawables are located? I want to switch some out (`Button` background png's, `EditText`s, etc), but I don't know where in the source tree they are.

If anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may want to check out http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are located in: frameworks\base\core\res\res